# What does N mean after a runway visual range (in a METAR)?

Tags: metar

This morning's METAR for Cambridge looked like this:

```
EGSC 110720Z 11001KT 0150 R23/0200N R05/0175N FZFG BKN001 M02/M02 Q1028
```

Note the bold runway visual range (RVR) indications. What does the `N` mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RVR often has a letter at the end to indicate the visibility trend, so you can tell if it's going to improve (and maybe you should circle overhead for a while) or worsen (and you should consider going to your alternate).

`U` means an "upward" trend: visibility is improving. `D` means a "downward" trend: visibility is worsening. `N` means **no change**.